# Django: how to filter on a sum of two fields in a related model?

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-models

I have a model basically like this:

```
class Unit(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)

class UnitPrice(models.Model):
    unit       = models.ForeignKey(Unit, related_name="prices")
    agency_fee = models.DecimalField(default=0.0, max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)
    owner_fee  = models.DecimalField(default=0.0, max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)
    def amount(self):
        return self.owner_fee + self.agency_fee
```

Is there a way to filter for `amount` (i.e. the sum of `agency_fee` and `owner_fee`) from `Unit.objects`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[`extra()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#extra) can help you

```
UnitPrice.objects.extra(where=["agency_fee + owner_fee > 10"])
```

Answer (score 17):

Or simply transform `a + b > c` to `a > c - b` in order to use [`models.F` expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#filters-can-reference-fields-on-the-model):

```
UnitPrice.objects.filter(agency_fee__gt=10-models.F('owner_fee'))
```