# Is it possible to apply a queryset method on sum of two fields

Tags: django

I have a `price` field and a `shipping` field on a model.

I need to add the value of both and use them as part of a `Q` object query. Ideally, something like:

```
if '1' in selected_prices:
  query |= Q(price_and_shipping__range=(1, 1000))

if '2' in selected_prices:
  query |= Q(price_and_shipping__range=(1001, 2000))
```

I know I can't just create a `price_and_shipping` property and use that, but what are the alternatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a great way to resolve this using F() Expressions

```
if '1' in selected_prices:
  query |= Q(price__gte=1 - F('shipping'), price__lte=1000 - F('shipping'))

if '2' in selected_prices:
  query |= Q(price__gte=1001 - F('shipping'), price__lte=2000 - F('shipping'))
```

Figured this out using this answer to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10664491/152653

More on F() expressions: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#query-expressions